# Extend PatternLayout in Log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

Since Log4J2's `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout` Class is `final`, I can't extend it to create headers for my **CSV**.

I referred docs, it doesn't provide info on how to extend existing Layout.
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Layouts

Previous approach of extending PatternLayout doesn't work.

My goal is to add header to log file & headers should be configured through configuration file for below log,

```
<File name="MttPerformance" fileName="logs\MyLog.csv" append="true">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy},%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS},%m%n"/>
</File>
```

Comment: Can you post an example that shows what you want to accomplish? Posting the class that extends `PatternLayout` would be helpful too.

Comment: I want to add header for CSV produced by 
<File name="MttPerformance" fileName="logs\myLog.csv" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy},%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS},%m%n"/>
        </File>

Comment: With old Log4j, it was done as explained in http://www.coderanch.com/t/535099/oa/Inserting-Header-Text-Log-file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy},%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS},%m%n" header="Date,Time,Inf,Time(ms)${sys:line.separator}"/>
```

Log4j2 has header tag..!
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Comment: Log4j2 supports headers and footers in layouts out of the box without requiring customization.

Comment: @RemkoPopma If still one wants to extend PatternLayout in log4j2, how can he proceed?

Comment: I would raise a ticket on the log4j 2 JIRA issue tracker.

Comment: @Gaurav Have you found a solution by now?